# Unable to read parameters from package.json

Tags: npm, package.json

I am unable to read parameters from package.json, so it's always $(directory).
and this is my command:

```
npm run migrate -- -directory "migration_dir"
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "XXXX",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "XXX",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "migrate": "cd $(directory)"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "XXXX"
  ],
  "author": "XXXX",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you may be facing is two-fold.

### 1. Arguments syntax for run-script

From [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

> As of npm@2.0.0, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option `--` is used by getopt to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script:
>
> ```
> npm run test -- --grep="pattern"
> ```

Arguments after `--` will be passed **directly**, in your case that is

```
$ cd $(directory) -directory "migration_dir"
```

To fix that, you have to change your script definition accordingly:

```
"scripts": {
  "migrate": "cd"
}
```

And pass the directory with no `-directory` option:

```
$ npm run migrate -- "migration_dir"
```

This will execute

```
$ cd "migration_dir"
```

### 2. Scripts are executing in a subshell

The `migrate` script you posted is useless because all npm scripts are executed in subshells, and changing the working directory from inside a subshell doesn't make a difference when a subshell exits.

Although if your script does anything beyond `cd` that will work:

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "cd / && pwd"
}
```

Part of the script after `&&` will see the effect of `cd`, but your shell won't.

```
$ npm run foo
> cd / && pwd
/

$ pwd
/your/original/path
```

However, you can't specify additional arguments using `--` anymore (`npm run foo -- arg` will do `cd / && pwd arg`).

Answer (score 0):

It's look like You want to read a `ENV` parameter. Bash notation is `${directory}` not `$(directory)`.

Now You can run migration

```
directory="migration_dir" npm run migrate
```

The output is

```
cd migration_dir
```

Pros of this solution is possibility of use complicated scripts.